# HQL Selecting only some subclass entities through implicit polymorphism

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I have a root class in my project defined as:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "entities")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class CommonEntity implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "entity_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Long id

}
```

i have several other classes that inherit it, like users, dogs (don't ask :P), comments, images, imageGlaeries,...

i need a way to select objects from my CommonEntity table, but so i only get those objects that belong to four specified subclasses. I'm currently trying this:

```
"SELECT listItem FROM CommonEntity listItem WHERE ((listItem.class='DogEntity' and listItem.isActive = true) or listItem.class='UserEntity') or (listItem.class='DogShowEntity' or listItem.class='PageEntity') ORDER BY listItem.createdTime desc"
```

but it is not working. I don't have a discriminator column declared, and i don't think i'd be allowed to make one. is there a way to make this work?

Comment: SELECT listItem.* FROM CommonEntity... might work. can you please check it ?

Comment: that did not help, but i did manage to solve the problem. it turned out that a different COUNT query was causing an issue somehow. thanks for your input tho :)